# php -> operator used in cascade

Tags: php

I saw this code:

```
 public function query( $query )
    {
        $full_query = $this->link->query( $query );
        if( $this->link->error )
        {
            $this->log_db_errors( $this->link->error, $query );
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

included in a class definition.
Please explain what this kind of code means: `a->b->c`. I know that `a->b` is used When accessing a method or a property of an instantiated class. But can not understand how to interpret("read,understand,translate") `a->b->c`

Comment: It means exactly the same, just like `$foo[33]` is conceptually the same as `$foo[33][44]`.

Answer (score 6):

It means that property b of object a is also an object. So you're getting property c of property b of object a.

```
class a {
    public $b;

    function __construct() {
        $this->b = new b;
    }
}

class b {
    public $c;

    function __construct() {
        $this->c = 'Hello';
    }
}

$a = new a;

echo $a->b->c; // outputs Hello.
```

Comment: Many thanks; both you and "The Head Rush". So one more question related to this subject. How long could be this chain ? So: property of property of property........of ....of.......object.

Comment: You won't usually see more than 4 but there's no limit (at least not that I'm aware of). If you need more than 4 you're doing something wrong. To answer your other question a property can have a property if it's an object.

Comment: To be more clear about my last question: can we declare a property of a class as being an object of another class?. Sounds like crazy world; we do not know who was the first: the egg or the chicken......

Comment: Yes that was precisely what my example above demonstrates. In class `a` you're declaring your property, `b`, as being an object of class `b`.

Comment: Excuse me I insist, it clear from docs that an object can have properties. What I did not see/find in docs is that a property can be an object. In most books I saw property is a variable and member/method is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Object a has a property, b, that is itself an object having c as a method or property. In terms of the code posted, $this, the object whose source you are viewing has a property -link - that is an object. Since link is also an object, it can (and does) have properties, two of which are query and error.

Comment: Many thanks; both you and "The Head Rush". So 2 more questions related to this subject. How long could be this chain ? So: property of property of property........of ....of.......object. And, can a property  to have a property? I thought only a class/object has properties and methods/members. I am confused of this mixture. Maybe  recomend me a good tutorial book that clarify this subject.